# Mechanism for passing data from one callback to another

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, android-handler

I want to use Speech to text in my app for actions such as click of a yes or no button.
I implemented the speech to text in my app.

In that I have a callback method called

```
   public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {

   //here I am getting Yes or No commands via User's Speech
   //bundle object has the data yes/no

   }
```

I want to use the result above as an input for some other task which are running in different threads, like for playing or pausing music and turning flash light on or off.

For doing this consider I have these methods below

```
music.play()
music.pause()
flashlight.on()
flashlight.off()
```

My question is how can I create such a mechanism so that I use Speech to text callback result data and pass it to different task's running in an separate threads and call `music.play()` or `flashlight.on()`

I tried to use Handlers for this with `sendmessage()` and `handlemessage()` methods.
But I am not able to figure out how can I implement it when main thread is not involved. Because my other task's are there in separate threads.

Can anyone help me with a prototype for this or just the data flow process will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bus-Message (event oriented) way can fit for your problem. F.e. we have **SomeEventHappenedMessage** class with some data inside. When some event is happens, message is sent through the bus and listeners will obtain it.

You can write your own bus or use EventBus library https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus for sending and obtaining messages/events.

Pseudocode:

```
//listener registers/unregisters when needed
Bus.register()
Bus.unregister()

//listener listens for message
onMessage(SomeEventHappenedMessage msg) {
    if msg.hasSomeData {
         music.play()
    } else {
         music.stop()
    }
}

//message being sent
SomeEventHappenedMessage message = (message creation)
Bus.sendMessage(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of callback logic, that requires cross communication to different tasks and threads I typically use Reactive Extensions for Android (RxAndroid), specifically Observables.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid

You can create and watch Observables on different threads, basically subscribing to watch a variable, then when the value changes your app logic can react in response to the change.

Read more about multi-Threading and RxJava here:

https://blog.gojekengineering.com/multi-threading-like-a-boss-in-android-with-rxjava-2-b8b7cf6eb5e2

Depending on the architecture of your app, a good way to do this is by have a central App Data Manager, that other components can access. By setting up the Observables on the App Data Manager, other app components can then subscribe to watch the variables they are interested in and react to changes.

Typically I base my Java based Android app designs off the amazing Android MVP Architecture from Mindorks, which extensively uses RxJava and Observables.

https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvp-architecture

Comment: Thank you @WildStyle for your answer. I presume its very good and optimal way of solving such problem. I am looking forward to learn RxAndroid and use it in my future projects. However for this case I was not looking for this answer. My original code is much more complex and bounded by handler so I am unable to use this at this point